# Scenekit physicsWorld Speed- slow motion effect

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to achieve slow motion effect by changing `speed` property of the `physicsWorld`. There are some objects in my scene that thrown up and affected by gravity. By touching an object, I want the whole scene gets slowed down, remove that object, and then back to the normal speed. I thought I could nest `SCNTransaction` but the completion is triggered immediately. I suppose that's because of SceneKit animation process like UIView Completion which is triggered when other animation is taking place. How can one achieve slow motion in SceneKit?

```
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = (0.5)
        SCNTransaction.animationTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        SCNTransaction.completionBlock =  {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = (0.5)
            self.scnScene.physicsWorld.speed = 1
            NSLog("animate finished")
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
        NSLog("animating")
        self.scnScene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.2
        node.removeFromParentNode()
        SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Your completion block probably gets triggered because `phsysicsWorld.speed` is not an animatable property and can't be animated with `SCNTransaction`

Comment: @orangenkopf danke. ich werde mal mit GCD versuchen.